# Reasons why Redux store change could trigger unwanted re-render in App.tsx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, dependencies

A Basic App.tsx file has no dependencies listed for re-render

```js
    export default function App():JSX.Element {
    session: SessionState = useAppSelector((state) => state.session);
        console.log("App file reloaded");
        return (
          <div>
              <ChildComponent />
              {session.cookieConsent ? null : <CookieConsent />}
          </div>
       );
    }
```

**ChildComponent** is the only component to:

- list redux state `session` as a dependency
- update the `session` state store.

```js
    const session: SessionState = useAppSelector((state) => state.session);
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    ...
    dispatch(setSession({ ...session, updated }));  // state change is perfect
    useEffect(()=>{},[session])
```

The main question is why would App.tsx file reload if a child component is updating redux state/store?  How does one stop this from happening?

Comment: You have `const session: any = useAppSelector((state) => state.session);` in the `App` component, so if `state.session` changes it will rerender

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I made that change (locally and above) and the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using the `session` constant in App.tsx for? If you remove that line (`const session: SessionState = useAppSelector((state) => state.session);`) from App.tsx, it shouldn't ever rerender.

Comment: That is the solution.  If any child member of `session` was edited it forced full re-render